# DNS cache snooping protection

Tags: dns, server, snooping

Is it possible to protect against DNS cache snooping on ISC bind and PowerDNS servers?
If not, is there a similar DNS server software which can't protect agains snooping?

Answer (score 1):

Because cache snooping is enabled by a properly operating caching DNS server, there's no way for the DNS server to thwart it without breaking proper caching behavior.  For example, you could make a DNS server hand out all responses with a synthetic TTL, but then the use case of having individual TTL for different records is being overridden.

It is possible to poison the cache as a defensive measure.  For example, let's say the attacker is using the cache to identify anti-virus software in use.  If the defender has a program which regularly queries the DNS records used by various anti-virus software *that isn't in use*, then the attacker will be get indicators for multiple anti-virus packages, with most of them being false.

I wrote a program to do this a couple years ago called [dnSense](https://github.com/gowenfawr/dnSense).

Comment: I only found this for a DNS server which is not common:
https://support.simpledns.plus/kb/a125/what-is-dns-cache-snooping-and-how-do-i-prevent-it.aspx

Comment: @jwalker ...which tells you how to turn the cache off completely.  Yes, that will prevent cache snooping, at the cost of "breaking proper caching behavior."